# I need to show what are the files are missing?? in front end user view. i have an error of undefined offset:0 in codeigniter.

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/Admin_user.php

Line Number: 1010

Backtrace:

File: /var/app/current/application/models/Admin_user.php
Line: 1010
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/app/current/application/controllers/Adminuser.php
Line: 427
Function: force_recheck

File: /var/app/current/index.php
Line: 319
Function: require_once

```
   public function force_recheck($jid)
   {
       $status=0;
       $job_details=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM prins_job_details WHERE jid='".$jid."' AND (status='-1' OR status='2')")->result();
       $agent_details=$this->db->get_where('prins_agents',array('agent_id'=>$job_details[0]->agent_id))->result();
       $s3_list=$this->listobject($job_details[0]->s3_path,$agent_details[0]->bucket_name);
       if($job_details[0]->json_list != $s3_list['count'])
       {
           $keys=$s3_list['keys'];
           for($i=0;$i<$s3_list['count'];$i++)
           {
               $position=strrpos($keys[$i]['Key'],"/");
               $name=substr($keys[$i]['Key'],$position + 1);
               $s3_keys[]=$name; 
           }
           $dynamic_fields=json_decode($job_details[0]->dynamic_fields,true);
           for($j=0;$j<count($dynamic_fields);$j++)
           {
               if($dynamic_fields[$j]['typevalue']=='image' || $dynamic_fields[$j]['typevalue']=='video')
               {
                  $json_keys[]=$dynamic_fields[$j]['value'];  
               }

           }
           $missing_key=array_diff($json_keys,$s3_keys);

           $template='<div class="row-fluid">';
               $template .='<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 center">';
                    $template .='<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bulk_action">';
                    $template .='<tr>';
                    $template .='<th>These Files are Not uploaded</th';
                    $template .='</tr>';
                    $template .='<tr>';
                    $template .='<th class="center">Missing Files</th';
                    $template .='</tr>';
                    for($n=0;$n<count($missing_key);$n++)
                    {
                        $template .='<tr><td class="prins-warning">';
                        $template .=$missing_key[$n]; // line number 1010 error
                        $template .='</td></tr>';    //undefined offset error
                    }
                    $template .='</table>';
               $template .='</div>';
           $template .='</div>';
           return $template;
       }
```

Comment: Please format your code..

Comment: Usually the tilte is considered to contain a summary of your problem... The body is usually used to explain your situation, problems, tries on solving the problem etc. and not for throwing around with unformatted code!

Comment: Please read [how can I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then reformat your question accordingly.